# How to retrieve available RAM from Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

Is there a command line utility within Windows or third-party program that can retrieve available RAM on a machine? (Since I don't believe this can be done in pure JAVA, since it is run within a virtual machine, that has preset / allocated RAM)?

Comment: Your question title is a bit different from the question text. Would you rather retrieve it in java?

Comment: @diggingforfire If possible, the suggestions so far are not very good

Comment: Your actual question "How to retrieve available RAM from Windows command line" has already been answered. You should be more clear, if your question was intended to be "How to retrieve available RAM from Windows in java", then the title is misleading. But even the answer to that has already been given. You can simply parse the output from the `systeminfo` command.

Answer (score 46):

`systeminfo` is a command that will output system information, including available memory

Comment: upvoted it's native; but it's localized and rounds and adds commas. `Total Physical Memory:     3,794 MB`

Answer (score 34):

```
wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory /Value
```

Comment: Would anyone know what units the value it gives back is?  I thought it was Bytes but my math doesn't otherwise workout to the true value I have

Answer (score 22):

Use `wmic computersystem get TotalPhysicalMemory`. E.g.:

```
C:\>wmic computersystem get TotalPhysicalMemory
TotalPhysicalMemory
4294500352
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant available memory, rather then total memory

Comment: upvoted for Single Numeral Output With Header - `TotalPhysicalMemory\n1234567890`

Answer (score 10):

```
wmic OS get TotalVisibleMemorySize /Value
```

Note not `TotalPhysicalMemory` as suggested elsewhere

Comment: This won't give the available RAM but the total RAM. For the available RAM, the answer by @Everardo is the correct one - `wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory /Value`

Comment: @OrangeDog What OS? Just tried this on Win7 x64 and Windows 10 x64 - it's still valid.

Answer (score 9):

There is a whole bunch of useful low level tools from [SysSnternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021).

And [`psinfo`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897550) may be the most useful.

I used the following psinfo switches:

```
-h        Show installed hotfixes.
-d        Show disk volume information.
```

Sample output is this:

```
c:> psinfo \\development -h -d

PsInfo v1.6 - local and remote system information viewer
Copyright (C) 2001-2004 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


System information for \\DEVELOPMENT:
Uptime: 28 days, 0 hours, 15 minutes, 12 seconds
Kernel version: Microsoft Windows XP, Multiprocessor Free
Product type Professional
Product version: 5.1
Service pack: 0
Kernel build number: 2600
Registered organization: Sysinternals
Registered owner: Mark Russinovich
Install date: 1/2/2002, 5:29:21 PM
Activation status: Activated
IE version: 6.0000
System root: C:\WINDOWS
Processors: 2
Processor speed: 1.0 GHz
Processor type: Intel Pentium III
Physical memory: 1024 MB
Volume Type Format Label Size Free Free
A: Removable 0%
C: Fixed NTFS WINXP 7.8 GB 1.3 GB 16%
D: Fixed NTFS DEV 10.7 GB 809.7 MB 7%
E: Fixed NTFS SRC 4.5 GB 1.8 GB 41%
F: Fixed NTFS MSDN 2.4 GB 587.5 MB 24%
G: Fixed NTFS GAMES 8.0 GB 1.0 GB 13%
H: CD-ROM CDFS JEDIOUTCAST 633.6 MB 0%
I: CD-ROM 0% Q: Remote 0%
T: Fixed NTFS Test 502.0 MB 496.7 MB 99%
OS Hot Fix Installed
Q147222 1/2/2002
Q309521 1/4/2002
Q311889 1/4/2002
Q313484 1/4/2002
Q314147 3/6/2002
Q314862 3/13/2002
Q315000 1/8/2002
Q315403 3/13/2002
Q317277 3/20/2002
```

Answer (score 8):

Bit old but I wanted to know similar. Just adding the solution I came across since IMO the best answer came from Everardo w/ Physical Memory

> `wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory /Value`

This lead me to look deeper into wmic... Keep in mind Free Physical Memory is not the type to look at.

`wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory,FreeVirtualMemory,FreeSpaceInPagingFiles /VALUE`

This returns something like...

```
FreePhysicalMemory=2083440
FreeSpaceInPagingFiles=3636128
FreeVirtualMemory=842124
```

Comment: isn't it TotalVisibleMemorySize ?

Answer (score 5):

```
PS C:\Users\Rack> systeminfo | findstr "System Memory"
System Boot Time:          5/5/2016, 11:10:41 PM
System Manufacturer:       VMware, Inc.
System Model:              VMware Virtual Platform
System Type:               x64-based PC
System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Total Physical Memory:     40,959 MB
Available Physical Memory: 36,311 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  45,054 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 41,390 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    3,664 MB
```

Comment: Perhaps better changing the string to just "Memory" viz. systeminfo | findstr "Memory". This will only give you back five entries, all connected with memory

Answer (score 2):

Powershell version of the posted wmic commands:

```
Get-CIMInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select *memory*

FreePhysicalMemory     : 1507688
FreeVirtualMemory      : 2131128
MaxProcessMemorySize   : 137438953344
TotalVirtualMemorySize : 13639352
TotalVisibleMemorySize : 8214848
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done in pure java. But you can run external programs using java and get the result.

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("systeminfo");
Scanner scan=new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
while(scan.hasNext()){
    String temp=scan.nextLine();
    if(temp.equals("Available Physical Memmory")){
       System.out.println("RAM :"temp.split(":")[1]);
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try MemLog. It does the job perfectly and quickly.

Download via one of many mirrors, e.g. this one: [SoftPedia page for MemLog](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/MEMLOG-Download-136937.html).
([MemLog's author has a web site](http://www.jfitz.com/dos/index.html#MEMLOG). But this is down some times. Wayback machine snapshot [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150912034516/http://www.jfitz.com/dos/index.html#MEMLOG).)

Example output:

```
C:\>memlog
2012/02/01,13:22:02,878956544,-1128333312,2136678400,2138578944,-17809408,2147352576
```

`878956544` being the free memory

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure [`Java`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) solution actually:

```
public static long getFreePhysicalMemory()
{
    com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean bean =
            (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)
                    java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
    return bean.getFreePhysicalMemorySize();
}
```

Comment: Please note: this is platform-specific and may not be available on all hardware / software platforms.

Comment: @Nick: But it generally works on `Windows` so it's already a good start

Comment: yes, you are correct, sorry, i should have pointed that out since the question was windows specific.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need this functionality in a Java program, you might want to look at the sigar API: http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar

Actually, this is no answer to the question, I know, but a hint so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

As the question was about the available RAM form a window commande line, here is the answer :

```
c:\>wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory
```

you can get all the information you need about memory and other things using the global commande

```
c:\>wmic OS
```

After that you'll only have the add a filter using get yourFilterName

Hope this will help ;)