# In tcl how to get the amount of RAM memory available

Tags: windows, memory, tcl

I have some code which reads larger big files. Depending on the file size I want to
a) read and treat the file line by line
b) if not to large, first read the whole file to memory and then do the work.

But how can I get the amount of currently free RAM on a windows computer using TCL.

I found the memory command, but that seems to be more suited if you want to find out how much memory your code is using, not how much is left on the computer in total...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how can I get the amount of currently free RAM on a windows
>   computer using TCL.

You will have to call out from Tcl, using [exec], to a Windows utility program ([`wmic`, `psinfo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095948/how-to-retrieve-available-ram-from-windows-command-line)) to obtain this info and then process it in Tcl.

Alternatively, you could also get the Tcl extension `TWAPI` and use its built-in introspection utility [`get_memory_info`](https://twapi.magicsplat.com/v4.2/osinfo.html#get_memory_info), with its option `-availphysical`.